# How to Retrieve Dynamic Columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i have a table

```
 EmpId  FirstName       LastName     Domain Vertical    Account City
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 345    Priya            Palanisamy DotNet  LS  Abbott  Chennai
 346    Kavitha     Amirtharaj DotNet   CG  Diageo  Chennai
 647       Kala          Haribabu     DotNet    IME IMS Chennai
```

i want to take the particular columns dynamically.i am using following Procedure but i can take only one column at a time..

```
    create PROC columnlist
    (
    @COLUMNS VARCHAR(1000)
    )
    AS
    BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = 'SELECT '+ @COLUMNS + ' FROM Table';
    exec sp_executesql @sql,N''

    END
```

i want to pass comma seperated values as a parameter to this Procedure.My Question is How to retrive table columns dynamically?

Comment: Your question makes no sense. What are you passing to the stored procedure?

Comment: What is the question? What does not work? Is there a error message?

Comment: My question is how to retrive the table columns dynamically sql using stored procedure?     Thanks in advance

Comment: do you means you want select n number of column.

Comment: What is the problem you are facing when passing comma separated column name ? it should work , any issue you are facing.

Comment: I'll pass column names as a parameter

Comment: i can pass only one column as a parameter. if i pass 2 columns it shows error like 'too many arguments specified'

Comment: yes i want to select n number of columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
CREATE PROCEDURE columnlist
(
  @COLUMNS VARCHAR(MAX)
)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)
  SET @sql = 'SELECT '+ @COLUMNS + ' FROM Table1'
  EXECUTE(@sql)
END
```

Use it

```
EXECUTE columnlist 'FirstName, LastName'
```

Here is **[SQLFIddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/17aa2/2)** demo

Comment: Did you take a look at sqlfiddle demo that I provided? What is not working? Post the code how you call the procedure.

Comment: +1 - for the good answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one -

**Query**

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.udf_GetTableColumns
(
    @Table NVARCHAR(100)
)
RETURNS DATETIME
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(MAX)

     SELECT @cols = STUFF((
          SELECT ', [' + c.name + ']' 
          FROM sys.columns c WITH(NOWAIT)
          WHERE c.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID(@Table)
          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '')

     RETURN @cols

END
```

**Exec**

```
SELECT dbo.udf_GetTableColumns('dbo.Table')
```